# Button disable after javascript validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scripting

I have a validation in a grid textbox for the date ranges, if the javascript validates date ranges are fine, i can click the add button and add new row in the grid.

But when the validation fails , i need to correct the date range , after correcting it javacript validates success fully but when i click on add button, this button control seems disabled.

What we can do for this?

Sample code :

```
case "dateRange":
                     var classGroup = "[" + options.validateAttribute + "*=" + rules[i + 1] + "]";

                     var rowCount = $('table.datagrid tr').length - 1;

                     var firstOfGroup = form.find(classGroup).eq(rowCount - 2);
                     var secondOfGroup = form.find(classGroup).eq(rowCount - 1);


                     if (rowCount > 1) {
                         //if one entry out of the pair has value then proceed to run through validation
                         if (firstOfGroup[0].value || secondOfGroup[0].value) {
                             errorMsg = methods._dateRange(firstOfGroup, secondOfGroup, rules, i, options);
                         }
                         if (errorMsg) required = true;
                         options.showArrow = false;
                     }
                     break;
```

Comment: Let me know any other code you require? Above one is the javascript validation code which fires if date range is wrong.

Comment: when JS function return false, postback will be canceled. i think that is happening here